# CSS animation conflict with !important in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have created an image slider with CSS animation, synchronously changing a button field and the images 
[Screenshot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Sd9.png)

The HTML code looks like this

```
<p class="slidercontrol">
 <span class="btn-border"><span id="btn-1" class="btn-tab slide_1"> 1 </span></span>
 <span class="btn-border"><span id="btn-2" class="btn-tab slide_2"> 2 </span></span>
 <span class="btn-border"><span id="btn-3" class="btn-tab slide_3"> 3 </span></span>
 <span class="btn-border"><span id="btn-4" class="btn-tab slide_4"> 4 </span></span>
 <span class="btn-border"><span id="btn-5" class="btn-tab slide_5"> 5 </span></span>
        </p>
<figure class="slidercss">
 <img id="img-1" class="slider_img slide_1" src="slider/hotel/slider-1.jpg" alt="">
 <img id="img-2" class="slider_img slide_2" src="slider/hotel/slider-2.jpg" alt="">
 <img id="img-3" class="slider_img slide_3" src="slider/hotel/slider-3.jpg" alt="">
 <img id="img-4" class="slider_img slide_4" src="slider/hotel/slider-5.jpg" alt="">
 <img id="img-5" class="slider_img slide_5" src="slider/hotel/slider-7.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```

For the animation I have introduced one @keyframe for each pair of button/image, changing parameters for both elements at the same time:

```
.slide_1 {animation: imgslide-1 infinite 15000ms;}
.slide_2 {...}
@keyframes imgslide-1 {
             0% {opacity: 1; background-color: #ff7d00; color: white;}
            15% {opacity: 1; background-color: #ff7d00; color: white;}
            25% {opacity: 0; background-color: #ffffff; color: #333333;}
           100% {opacity: 0; background-color: #ffffff; color: #333333;}
}
@keyframe imgslide-2 {....
```

In the keyframe the opacity has to change for the image and the background-color and color attribute for the button.
To show always the button content, all buttons are set to opacity 1 with important:

```
.btn-tab {opacity: 1 !important;}
```

Firefox does it very well, and takes the "!important" attribute and shows always the button, regardless of the change of opacity in the keyframe.
But Chrome 70 prefers the opacity statement from the keyframe and ignores the "!important" statement, so the button content fades out like the image.
Is it a bug or a feature or did I do someting wrong?

Here is the life-page with my problem: https://www.proaspecto.com/de/webdesign-referenzen/fallstudie-hotel-website.html

Can anyone help?

Comment: I agree with Chrome; the animation should play even if there happen to be style rules with higher specificity in the stylesheet. Because the `animation` property is a property like any other, and you don't have an `!important` on that! The solution is to create a separate keyframe for the buttons, that doesn't change the opacity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I tried to have one class with the same keyframe statement out of the idea to get synchronicity for the elements.

Comment: I wouldn’t agree that’s the best solution. Normally you can define everything without important on the basic level, than you have the animation, as next highest and on top you still might change this with important. We would have three real levels and I would say this is more flexible in Design.
Nevertheless, I can understand that they assume a lot of websites work with frameworks and then have many overwrites with !important which blocks animation, thus only out of practical reasons animation must be on highest level out of. 
There should be a clarification which way to go for the browsers.